# Django ORM, accessing the attributes of relationships

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have on my projects two apps: account_app and image_app which have the models below.

I am wondering if it is possible to directly access the number of likes of one profile, which has a OneToOne relation with User(django bultin) that in turn has a ManyToMany relation with Images user_like.

***account_app/models.py***

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # quando usar a relacao nao colocar o nome User de vez, tem que usar dessa forma
    # essa relacao nos permite linkar o perfil com o usuario
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
```

***image_app/models.py***

```
class Image(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='images_created')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    url = models.URLField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    users_like = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='images_liked',blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also introduce a property `likes` in Profile Model.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # quando usar a relacao nao colocar o nome User de vez, tem que usar dessa forma
    # essa relacao nos permite linkar o perfil com o usuario
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)

    @property
    def likes(self):
        self.user.images_liked.count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a *Profile* instance `profile`, you may get the number of `users_like` with:

```
number_of_likes = profile.user.images_liked.count()
```